# vs code snippet: how to use variable transforms twice in a row

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

See the following snippet:

```
    "srcPath":{
    "prefix": "getSrcPath",
    "body": [
        "$TM_FILEPATH",
        "${1:${TM_FILEPATH/(.*)src.(.*)/${2}/i}}",
        "${TM_FILEPATH/[\\\\]/./g}"
    ]
},
```

The output of lines 1-3 is :

```
D:\root\src\view\test.lua
view\test.lua
D:.root.src.view.test.lua
```

How can I get output like 'view/test.lua'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
"srcPath":{
  "prefix": "getSrcPath",
  "body": [
      "$TM_FILEPATH",
      "${TM_FILEPATH/.*src.|(\\\\)/${1:+/}/g}",
      "${TM_FILEPATH/[\\\\]/\\//g}"
  ]
}
```

[image: transform on path snippet]

`.*src.|(\\\\)` will match everything up to and including the `...src\` path information.  We don't save it in a capture group because we aren't using it in the replacement part of the transform.

The `(\\\\)` matches any `\` in the rest of the path - need the `g` flag to get them all.

Replace: `${1:+/}` which means if there is a capture group 1 in `.*src.|(\\\\)` then replace it with a `/`.  Note we don't match the rest of the path after `src\` only the `\`'s that might follow it.  So, not matching those other path parts just allows them to remain in the result.

---

You were close on this one:

`"${TM_FILEPATH/[\\\\]/\\//g}"` just replace any `\\\\` with `\\/`.

Answer (score 0):

With the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates#insert-template-in-current-file) you can insert a "snippet" that contains a variable and multiple find-replace operations.

With a key binding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+f",  // or any other combo
    "command": "templates.pasteTemplate",
    "args": {
      "text": [
        "${relativeFile#find=.*?src/(.*)#replace=$1#find=[\\\\/]#flags=g#replace=.#}"
      ]
    }
  }
```

At the moment only possible with a key binding or via `multi command` (or similar). Will add an issue to also make it possible by prefix.

Also some of the standard variables are missing.